# How do you overload dynamically extended methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have some modules in an array. All the modules define a method called "process", and I'd like to call each of these process methods in sequence. The code I have looks something like this(assume the modules are all defined inside the Mod class):

```
modules.each do |mod|
  extend Mod.const_get(mod)
  process(data)
end
```

This works fine for the first time, but the method doesn't get overwritten after the first pass of the loop. I've tried adding `undef process` as the last line inside the `each` block but that didn't work.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modules can only be included into an inheritance chain once.

Also, what are you doing is really weird, you should think about redesigning your system.

Answer (score 2):

is making the 'process' method into a module-method an option (by defining it def self.process)?

If so, sending the method 'process' directly to the returned constant would work:

```
modules.each do |mod|
  Mod.const_get(mod).send(:process, data)
end
```

**EDIT**
Come to think of it, why not call the method directly?

```
  Mod.const_get(mod).process(data)
```